# I can't store or read NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

It seems something is going wrong, I can't store or read NSUserDefaults in my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray * defaultKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    @"FirstViewComposer",
                                    @"ProfileNickname",
                                    @"ProfileGender",
                                    @"ProfileDateOfBirth",
                                    @"ProfileFavoriteColor",
                                    @"ProfileHeight",
                                    nil];


NSArray * defaultValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                    @"YES",
                                    @"Me",
                                    @"Male",
                                    @"08 Dec 1983"
                                    @"Red",
                                    @"183",
                                    nil];

 NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:defaultValues forKey:defaultKeys];


 [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];

 NSLog(@"%@", [defaults stringForKey:@"FirstViewComposer"]); //null
```

thanks

**UPDATE**:
Now I'm synchronized, actually they are stored but I'm probably not retrieving them correctly:

```
2011-08-23 17:16:06.932 Sansnuage[1404:b603] defaults: (
        (
        en,
        fr,
        de,
        ja,
        nl,
        it,
        es,
        pt,
        "pt-PT",
        da,
        fi,
        nb,
        sv,
        ko,
        "zh-Hans",
        "zh-Hant",
        ru,
        pl,
        tr,
        uk,
        ar,
        hr,
        cs,
        el,
        he,
        ro,
        sk,
        th,
        id,
        "en-GB",
        ca,
        hu,
        vi
    ),
    1,
        (
        YES,
        Me,
        Male,
        "08 Dec 1983Red",
        183
    ),
    "en_US",
        (
        "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
    ),
        (
        en,
        fr,
        de,
        ja,
        nl,
        it,
        es,
        pt,
        "pt-PT",
        da,
        fi,
        nb,
        sv,
        ko,
        "zh-Hans",
        "zh-Hant",
        ru,
        pl,
        tr,
        uk,
        ar,
        hr,
        cs,
        el,
        he,
        ro,
        sk,
        th,
        id,
        "en-GB",
        ca,
        hu,
        vi
    ),
    macintosh
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to synchronize your data before retrieve them from disk. To do so you should use  [synchronize](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) method.

UPDATE:
You should change the way you try to store your appDefaults NSDictionary.
Try:

```
#define kAppDefaultEnty @"AppDefaultsEntry"
[defaults setObject:appDefaults forKey:kAppDefaultEnty];
```

And then synchronize it:

```
[defaults synchronize];
```